# How to "run method" from different android class

Tags: java, android

First and foremost, like so many, I have just recently began to try and learn Java and Android Development.  I am following some tutorials and so on.  Anyhow, I am attempting to do something that is probably very simple but I am unsure of syntax to complete, and because of such, not sure how to search it on the internet with any success.

My question:  I have a "Main.java" file and a second "Tabs.java".  The main has everything you would expect from a default stub:

```
package com.example.main;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My Tabs.java looks like:

```
package com.example.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class Tabs extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        //Initiate tabs
        TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();

        //Create tab1
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Reservation List");
        th.addTab(specs);
    }
}
```

My hope is to initiate this tabs class on program start, to setup a tabbed view.  I could throw it into the main class but I thought I would attempt to keep the code neater by separating them out.  How can I go about completing this?

Comment: Put it in the `Main Activity`. If you are only using `Main` to start this then `Main` is essentially useless. They are both `Activities` so it would be two different screens. You would go from `Activity` to `Activity` using `Intents`

Comment: Not sure this really warrants a down vote. It's not a totally unreasonable question with no thought behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "answer" is this is a bad idea. However, I think it is worth explaining why this is a bad idea. It sounds like you are confusing two fundimental concepts - that of a `class`, which exists in object oriented languages like `Java`, and that of an android `Activity`.

An `Activity` is really like a seperate program. It contains all (or at least most) of the material it needs to perform a specific task. An app can combine a number of activities to handle more than one kind of task - for example, in a messaging application, you may have one activity that displays a users contacts and another that allows you to send them a message. These activities are seperate. You can transfer data between them, as @codeMagic mentioned, by using `Intents` but for the most part each `Activity` is self contained.

A `class` is a concept from object oriented programming that serves as a blueprint from which objects of that type are created. The [Oracle Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) provides a good example of this concept. Classes are useful becuase they alow you set the properties of a kind of object that can be used later on in your application, greatly improving flexibility.

The chat application example I references above is a good way to understand where/how you would use a class. In that sitaution, when you had to display a person's contact list, you would not be able to know in advance for each user who would be contained in that list, what information you would be provided or how many individuals there would be. To deal with this situation you would create a `class` called user. The user class would contain all the details you wanted to display about a particular person. Maybe this would include their name, address, phone number, whatever. You could set a list of properties that apply generally to all users and then later create individual instances of the user class, and fill in the supplied data, for each person you wish to display.

In short - you're activity does not work the same way as a `class` (but see [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) which can behave similarly). For what you are trying to do, create the tabs in your main activity.